# Grease Pencil strokes from movie clip editor not showing in 3D view

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, grease-pencil, movie-clip-editor

Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I drew on top of a movie clip in the movie clip editor with the grease pencil. I have all those frames looking the way I want, but recently found out that I cannot render them that way, as it is only an in-memory representation of the strokes.

So, I went to the 3D view, put the grease pencil layers in my scene, and used the movie clip as a background image. My strokes don't show up there, even though I can draw new strokes that show up.

Is there a way to see the strokes I've made and to render them out?

movie clip editor:
[image: movie clip editor view with strokes]

3D view:
[image: 3d view with strokes not showing up]

Comment: I think that the Grease pencil is display dependent, so the one ou add only works in the view that you use. Sorry. Only way to render is from 3D view as OpenGL or VSE as OpenGL (I think).

Comment: A quick test suggests that you can define the MCE GP layer in the VSE and you could do  OpenGL render there. BUT the shape of the line doesn't follow. Sorry. Could be a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround! So what I ended up doing was to write a small script to change all the 2D strokes I made to 3D strokes:

```
gp = bpy.context.scene.grease_pencil
for l in gp.layers:
    for f in l.frames:
        for s in f.strokes:
            s.draw_mode='3DSPACE'
```

For some reason which I do not know, the 3D strokes were the correct orientation when I viewed them from the top orthographic view. Then I scaled and moved my background image to be behind the strokes the same way I had it before.